# How to: Target a local android dependency

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I'm trying to modify a flutter package but the part that needs changing is in an Android dependency being used by that package.

The flutter package is epub_viewer (https://pub.dev/packages/epub_viewer) which implements a modified version of FolioReader (https://github.com/JideGuru/Folioreader-Android) ...

I've been trying to follow examples on here but it doesn't make sense and keeps telling me it can't find the package https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

My file structure is like this:

```
../users/documents/epub_viewer
../users/documents/folioreader
```

and I need to change this dependency in epub_viewer's app `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.jideguru:folioreader:0.6.2"
    ...
}
```

Comment: hi Chris
I am facing the same problem , could you find any solution?

Comment: Hi, I don't think I ever managed to figure out how to use a local dependency but instead I uploaded the package I had modified to github and used this website https://jitpack.io/

Comment: @Chris I need help with the same, where did you get the files which you modified. I am stuck on this for days

Comment: @Dhruvbhati they are linked in the question at the top. I used the current dart `epub_viewer` package and point the dependency in the android/app `build.gradle` to a modified version of `Folioreader` that I have on my github account. I had to use https://jitpack.io to publish the android dependency before it would work.